# Loop in error handling

Tags: r, loops, error-handling

Premise:

I've written a function that calculates the "best" ARIMA model for a time series:I provide the function the maximum order of AR members, then it eliminates the insignificant AR members by the highest p-value.

Problem:

The Arima() function sometimes fails to calculate some of the models (e.g. maximum AR order is too high) and produces an error which can be usually fixed by introducing shorter maximum AR order.

How do I reduce the maximum order one by one until I get a model Arima() is able to compute?

I've written below a an example of the idea. We have 25 observation and we set the model to have 25 AR members (which is an overkill and produces an error). So the loop should reduce 25 to a lower number so the model can actually could be computed at a maximum length. Then the algorithm would kick in and find the most appropriate model.

```
ar.sim <- arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(0.9,-0.5)),n=500)
lmod1 <- Arima(ar.sim, order=c(40,0,0))

set.seed(12512)
ar.sim <- arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(0.9,-0.5)),n=25)
lmod1 <- Arima(ar.sim, order=c(40,0,0))
p=25

for (i in 1:23 ) {
        result = tryCatch({
        lmod1 <- Arima(ar.sim, order=c(p,0,0))
        }, error = function(e) {
        lmod2 <- Arima(ar.sim, order=c(p-i,0,0))
        })

}
```

However, lmod2 also produces and error which breaks the loop. It looks like the error part of the handling also needs a loop, but I'm not sure how to approach this? Any ideas would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: You should look at `failwith()` in package `plyr` which is useful for this purpose

Comment: I think you're working to hard, check out the `auto.arima` function in the `forecast` package. Also, if your code depends on a package (like the `Arima` function), be sure to mention it in your post.